# Распаковка .dpk-файла

Tags: flash, декомпиляция

Как и чем можно извлечь ресурсы из `.dpk` файла. Известно, что это чем-то запакованный `swf`.

[Пример файла](https://media-r03ru.rjgplay.com/resources/vk/common/data/data.dpk)